# how to use dispatch function of useContext hook inside a axios().then()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

in my component

```
axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `${SERVER_URL}crawler/get-customer/${uniqueId}`,
}).then(function (response) {
    if(response.data){
        console.log("response",response);
        responseData = response.data;
     dispatch({ type: 'SET_IMG', payload: { url: responseData.logo_url } });
    }
},[]);
```

response in coming as it should, but the dispatch is being recursive and almost crashed my browser, and the data 'url' is not updated

Comment: how and where are you executing your api request through axios

Comment: Using django local server, no problems in api request, I have solved this problem using useEffect () hook. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `${SERVER_URL}crawler/get-customer/${uniqueId}`,
    }).then(function (response) {
        if(response.data){
           console.log("response",response);
           responseData = response.data;
           props.functionName(response.data);
      }
},[]);

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
functionName: (data) => dispatch({
        type:'SET_IMG',
        payload: { url: responseData.logo_url }
    })
 }
}

export default connect(, mapDispatchToProps)(nameComponent);
```

Answer (score -1):

It would help if you could post your whole component, but I'll take a stab anyways...

I'm assuming your component is also taking the fetched data value out of the state (redux?), and then most likely this type of loops is happening:

- component renders
- fetch data
- update value in state (redux?)
- component renders because value was updated
- fetch data
- update value in state
- etc

Do you intend to only fetch the data once? If you do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios({...}).then(...);
}, []);
```

Comment: Don't stab, ask for clarifications and then answer when we have all the details.

Comment: Is this actually a rule? I feel like I listed my assumptions clearly which still leads to a beneficial response.

Comment: I used useEffect and it's working, thank you and I am not using REDUX. , just react hooks